GA4 total sessions don't match page-wise sessions. Any insights on why or how to fix it?
I'm facing an issue with my GA4 data and could use some help. I've noticed that the total sessions reported do not match the sum of the sessions reported on a page-by-page basis. For example, the total sessions in my report show one number, but when I sum the sessions for each individual page, the numbers don't add up.
Has anyone else encountered this issue? Is there a specific reason why total sessions and page-wise sessions might not align in GA4? Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve or understand this discrepancy would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

